How did the Concorde’s glide ratio vary from takeoff to supercruise?
I can't seem to get straight numbers on its glide ratio. One source claims 4:1 at takeoff and 12:1 at transonic speeds. But what about the supercruising phase that it's flight was optimized for?

It depends on the version:




A Model
B Model




Takeoff
3.94
4.24


Initial climb
4.97
5.58


Hold @250KTS & 10,000ft
9.27
13.1


Subsonic Cruise
11.47
12.92


Supersonic Cruise
7.14
7.69



Source: concordesst.com

Not even at the wayback machine.

Case Study by Aerospatiale and British Aerospace on the Concorde,
by Jean Rech and Clive S Leyman
ISBN (print): 978-1-56347-308-1eISBN: 978-1-60086-812-2
Publication Date: June 1, 1980.  Part of the AIAA Professional Study Series. Specifically, see figure 3.20 on page 3-21.

Also p11 of Nasa memo 75464, a translation of the original document (G. Cormery, 1977) which shows the difference between the two wings (planes A/B) and the efficiency gains.
